# Docker volume mounts just... don't work (SELinux related?)

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, redhat, selinux, redhat-containers

So I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/FSecureLABS/awspx) repo on an AWS EC2. It relies on a script featuring a `docker run` command, which I've been modifying as needed. However, due to restrictions that are beyond my control, I need to use SSL. So I added the requisite lines to my neo4j.conf file vis a vis the env variables. Now all I need to do is link my `bolt` directory as a volume to the container, and I *should* be off to the races. However, this is proving more difficult than I had imagined. The folder's contents are simply not present in the container at all. `docker inspect` indicates that the mount is successful at this point, with the following mount description:

```js
{
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "bolt",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/296608.296608/volumes/bolt/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/bolt",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
```

Upon writing this out, though, I'm realizing that the source in this description is very much not where I would expect it to be. I just tried using an absolute path (/opt/awspx/bolt/) to fix that and received the error informing me that that contains invalid  characters, and I should use an absolute path, which of course I have already done. Upon placing the files in this directory, they show up in the container... but I get a ton of `chown` errors. I manually executed chown on the contents of the folder, settings its owner to what the output of `id` suggests that the userid for docker should be. No dice.

I've taken the following steps and received the corresponding results:

- Tried to enable/disable SELinux mode.

  The EC2 comes with SELinux
  disabled, and upon enabling it to either "enforcing" or "permissive" mode, I can no longer `docker run` any containers at all. I instead receive

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:402: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused: EOF: unknown.`,

which I'm unable to remedy by any means I can find. That's a  whole separate stackoverflow question, haha. It's entirely possible there's a policy that is hidden from me and is intentionally preventing me from using SELinux, but I cannot confirm this. Upon re-disabling it, the EOF-related error disappears.

- using an absolute path instead of a local one (I think is what caused this result)

  This simply caused a slew of permission errors. I was unable to start the docker container due to consistent and repeated chown failures, even after setting the owner of the folder to be the docker user.
- changed the mount to `volume` from `bind`

  No change.
- Changed mount name from `ssl` to `bolt`

  No change.

Most interestingly, this worked on a different EC2 that I had to terminate for an unrelated reason. I have no idea why this isn't functioning as expected.

Comment: Is this Red Hat related ? Should be tagged accordingly

Comment: By the way, in order to make sure it is SElinux related, simply turn the policy to either `disabled` or `permissive`, by editing /etc/selinux/conf. This is what I usually do when I want to point the finger at SElinux for such problems.

Comment: You can do `setenfoce 0` to check if it's selinux related. It will disable selinux temporarily.

Comment: @Veverke SElinux is currently set to disabled. If I set it to either "enforcing" or "permissive" like I said in my post, i get a different error. This is Amazon Linux, so yes it is red hat. I'll try to change the tags accordingly. My instinct to solve the volume permission error was to use the :z flag on my docker -v argument, but that doesn't make any sense if selinux is disabled, which it apparently is by default. However, this could be an intentional setting from my organization. I'm mostly looking to mount the folder to that place in the filesystem by any means.